# Per site Hot Questions list has wrong page title

Tags: bug, hot-questions, window-title, hot-tab

On any Stack Exchange site front page, when mouse hover on the [hot tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=hot), the tool tip says:

> Questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days

And the questions are indeed displaying for the last few days.

But in the browser title it shows **Hottest Questions Today**, actually it is not showing only the hot questions of **today**, for the last few days questions.

The [week tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=week) shows the last 7 days hot questions, [month tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=month) shows last 30 days hot questions and the browser title is **Hottest Questions This Week**, **Hottest Questions This Month** respectively.

So for the [hot tab](https://stackapps.com/?tab=hot) the browser title need to be change according to it's tool tip content.

[image: Hot Today]